# Why is y-axis wrapped in xyplot for longitudinal data?

Tags: r, lattice

I am doing a project on Functional Data Analysis, where I am trying to plot spaghetti plots for height. I am using xyplot from lattice library. Why is y-axis wrapped in xyplot?

Here I am plotting data for only one individual. If plot whole data set it looks like a block of thick lines.

My code in R is:

```
xyplot(height ~ age|sex, p_data, type="l", group=id)
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing `p_data` it's hard to say, but based upon the axis labelling I would guess that `height` is being treated as a factor variable.

Run `is.factor(p_data$height)`, and if the answer is `TRUE` then try

`p_data$height <- as.numeric(levels(p_data$height))[p_data$height]`

and repeat your plot. If this doesn't work then at least give us some idea of what the `p_data` dataframe looks like.

Comment: Indeed that was a problem, it was a factor. Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 1):

@Joe has put you on the right path. The issue is almost certainly that the `height` variable is being treated as a factor (categorical variable) rather than a continuous, numeric variable:

E.g. - I can replicate a similar problem via:

```
p_data <- data.frame(height=c(96,72,100,45),age=1:4,sex=c("m","f","f","m"),id=1)
p_data$height <- factor(p_data$height,levels=p_data$height)

# it's all out of order cap'n!
p_data$height
#[1] 96  72  100 45 
#Levels: 96 72 100 45

# same plot call as you are using    
xyplot(height ~ age|sex, p_data, type="l", group=id)
```

[image]

If you fix it up like so:

```
p_data$height <- as.numeric(as.character(p_data$height))
```

....then the same call gives an appropriate result:

```
xyplot(height ~ age|sex, p_data, type="l", group=id)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Height was a factor.